# Detect REMEMBER_ME status from login page in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to be able to detect if the current user session has the ROLE `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` from the **login page**. Obviously, the login page has no security context so I can't use isGranted/is_granted, etc. I can't figure out any reliable way to do this since Symfony deletes the security token before calling the authentication entry point before redirecting to the login.

The reason behind this is I want to display a message saying something like "Please verify yourself" on the login page when a user tries to edit their profile w/o being fully authenticated (they logged in via a rememberme cookie).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can check for:

- `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` - automatically assigned to a user who
  is in a firewall protected part of the site but who has not actually
  logged in. This is only possible if anonymous access has been
  allowed.
- `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` - automatically assigned to a user who
  was authenticated via a remember me cookie.
- `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` - automatically assigned to a user that has
  provided their login details during the current session.

as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html). Have a look at "Forcing the User to Re-authenticate before accessing certain Resources"

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. I'm looking to check if the session that is attempting to login was redirected due to a REMEMBER_ME redirect. I might be able to setup my own authentication listener and simply set a session attribute before the redirect occurs.